# Why are two equivalent ISODate values not equal?

Tags: mongodb

Why do the last two statments return `false`?

```
test:PRIMARY> a = new ISODate(); b = a;
ISODate("2014-08-21T19:48:12.963Z")
test:PRIMARY> a === b;
true
test:PRIMARY> db.tmp.insert({blah:a,foo:b});
test:PRIMARY> c = db.tmp.findOne();
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("53f64d4916945e0b3a06788a"),
    "blah" : ISODate("2014-08-21T19:48:12.963Z"),
    "foo" : ISODate("2014-08-21T19:48:12.963Z")
}
test:PRIMARY> c.blah === c.foo;
false
test:PRIMARY> c.blah == c.foo;
false
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It may be comparing object references and not the actual date values. Try c.blah.getTime() === c.foo.getTime()

Comment: Exactly correct. `==` and `===` on two non-primitive types will test identity, not equality. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators for a reference.